# Updating my Mac's OpenSSL, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, openssl, installation

I'm updating OpenSSL on my Mac OS X 10.8.5.  I updated using the below commands and it seems to have succeeded.

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz
tar xzf openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz 
cd openssl-1.0.1g
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
make all
sudo make install
```

However, when I do a "openssl version" I still get "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013" even though I just did a make install with 1.0.1g.  Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Remember that 0.9.8y does _not_ contain the Heartbleed bug, so although 0.9.8y is older, it is not a risk.  With that said, double-check the install locations for that build and also make sure your `which openssl` points to the OS-installed version.  If you're using brew or ports, you need to update their versions (in lieu of or as well as).

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.  I backed up the old one and linked to the new one (I forgot how to do that process...)  A piece of opensource software I use told me that my version of openssl was vulnerable... So it seems there is a misunderstanding of which version are and are not vulnerable to the Heartbleed bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I do a "openssl version" I still get "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013" even though I just did a make install with 1.0.1g. Am I missing a step here?

The OpenSSL you built and installed is located in `/usr/local/ssl`. The program `openssl` is located in `/usr/local/ssl/bin`, the headers are located in `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl`, and the libraries are located in `/usr/local/ssl/lib`.

You are using the OpenSSL that came with Mac OS X in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ find /usr -iname openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
...
```

You can examine the details of the OpenSSL you installed by using the full path:

```
$ /usr/local/ssl/darwin/bin/openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1g-fips 7 Apr 2014
built on: Fri Apr 11 10:23:53 EDT 2014
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN
  -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT
  -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -I/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/include -DSHA1_ASM
  -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl/darwin/ssl"
```

You can change the installation directory with the following:

```
export KERNEL_BITS=64
./config --openssldir=XXX
```

You can also tune the installation with the following. If you are on a modern Mac, I believe `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` will give you a 2x to 4x speedup in EC operations (by using `uint128_t`):

```
export KERNEL_BITS=64
./config shared no-ssl2 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 --openssldir=XXX
```

Comment: Thanks!  I backed up the old one and linked to the new one (I forgot how to do that...)